# transitionEnd does not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, css

Although using the right prefix the transitionend event is not fired.

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1dhp66c7/)

**js**

```
var flyingCarElem = document.getElementById("flyingCar");

 // register an event handler 
   // ('transitionEnd' for FireFox, 'webkitTransitionEnd' for webkit) 
       flyingCarElem.addEventListener("transitionEnd",function(){
      // will be called when the transition has finished.
    alert("The car arrived");
     });
```

**css**

```
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
-webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */
transition: width 2s;
  } 

   div:hover {
width: 300px;
  }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: The event name is `transitionend`, not `transitionEnd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition end event in Firefox is called

```
transitionend
```

and not

```
transitionEnd
```

Your fix should be easy enough:

```
var flyingCarElem = document.getElementById("flyingCar");

 // register an event handler 
   // ('transitionend' for FireFox, 'webkitTransitionEnd' for webkit) 
       flyingCarElem.addEventListener("transitionend",function(){
      // will be called when the transition has finished.
    alert("The car arrived");
   });
```